# Asp.net mvc razor view string.format does not seems to work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using string.format to format my model value inside razor view but it does not gives desired result

```
@string.Format("{0:00}", Model.Range == null ? "" : Model.Range.ToString())
```

It should result as 05

if i am using below it gives me result but not from model

```
@string.Format("{0:00}", 5)
```

Someone have any idea or same experience ?

Comment: Try removing {0:00} with {0}

Comment: What type of "Range" ?

Comment: This is only a property of model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `Model.Range` is a number type then you need to write:

```
@string.Format("{0:00}", Model.Range == null ? "" : Model.Range)
```

because with the `Model.Range.ToString()` you have converted your `Range` to string so the number formatting cannot be applied because it is not a number anymore.

By the way `string.Format` handles null arguments so it is enough to write:

```
@string.Format("{0:00}", Model.Range)
```

If `Model.Range` is not a number but with `Model.Range.ToString()` you get a number in a string representation then you need to first convert it to a number (like using `int.Parse` or its other variants) then you can pass the number to `string.Format` which can now apply the correct formatting.

Comment: Thanks namesv this is exact explanation